# Count difference in PIG query and MySql query results in GROUP BY

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, sqoop

My PIG Query is given below

---

```
emp = LOAD 'hdfs://master:9000/hrms/DimEmployee' AS  (EmployeeID,OrganizationID,EmploymentType);
grouped = group emp by (OrganizationID, EmploymentType);
AggEmploymentType = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group.OrganizationID, group.EmploymentType,COUNT(emp.EmployeeID) as cnt;
DUMP AggEmploymentType;
```

---

Below given is the step by step description of above pig query.

1. LOAD 100097 records from HDFS file which is tab delimited.
2. Group by the records by Company,EmploymentStatus
3. Count the records by EmployeeID.
4. Dump the output.

After execution of above query, **Pig shell says, successfully read 100115 records.**

I am getting below given three problems after Pig query executes successfully:

1. Why pig is ready more records than available in HDFS
   (100115>100097)
2. Why There is warning message "ACCESSING_NON_EXISTENT_FIELD 27 TIMES"
3. The result has count difference of 9 when I run same group by query in MySQL.

**Please solve my problem as soon as possible. My pig,hadoop project is depending upon your prompt response. I am struck since last 5 days due to above problem**

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is coincidence that you are loading extra records and you are also getting accessing non existent fields error. The non existent field error shows up when you are loading and there aren't enough columns. For example, you might get the error if you see a line like: `hello,world` when you are expected 3 columns.

**Suggestion:** The other thing to note is that `COUNT(x)` does not count items that are null. Try swapping out `COUNT(emp.EmployeeID)` with `COUNT_STAR(emp.EmployeeID)`. `COUNT_STAR` takes nulls into account.

**Suggestion:** One thing that Pig will do when it doesn't have the fields is just put nulls in it. I suggest you add a filter before the `GROUP` that removes records with nulls (and also potentially "bad" records).

```
emp = FILTER emp BY EmployeeID IS NOT NULL AND 
                    OrganizationID IS NOT NULL AND
                    EmploymentType IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Hi orangoctopus,thanks for your response. I have also used COUNT_STAR but result is still same. I think the problem is in tab delimited file. Please advise, how to load tab delimited file properly in hdfs while importing using sqoop. So, that pig could read file properly and "Accessing non existent filed" problem does not come –